# Is it safe to call managed function from native class method?

Tags: .net, c++-cli, mixed-code

I have C++ dll with native interface (exported class), which is compiled with /clr switch. Some methods of exported class have `...` parameter. Compiler shows C4793 warning on this class: function is compiled as native code.

```
// ExportedClass.h
class LIBRARY_API ExportedClass
{
public:
    void Method(const char* format, ...);
};

// ExportedClass.cpp

void ManagedFunction()
{
    String^ s = gcnew String(L"");    // OK
}

void ExportedClass::Method(const char* format, ...)
{
    // Not allowed: the function is native
    // String^ s = gcnew String(L"");

    // Call ManagedFunction instead:
    ManagedFunction();
}
```

Since the class is compiled as native, I cannot use managed code directly in the class methods. However, I can call managed functions, as shown in the code sample. Is it safe to do this?

Comment: You are playing a pretty dangerous game, the CLR needs to be loaded and initialized before that managed function can execute.  You probably got that by accident now, the C++/CLI compiler will create a stub if necessary to get that done.  That stub is *not* cheap.  You also have no control whatsoever over what version of the CLR you get.  Using COM or hosting the CLR yourself is the safe version.

Comment: @HansPassant: This library is compiled with /cli, and referenced from the client through linker dependencies list. AFAIK, this means, that CLR is loaded when the process starts. Is this correct?